# Read Per-Frame Timecode with FFMPEG?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I want to read a per-frame timecode out of a video file using libav (FFMPEG).  I've started by digging into FFProbe.  Using this as a starting point for my code, I can get to the `AVStream` that has the timecode in it.  From there, I can use the dictionary to look at the stream's metadata.

```cpp
int show_stream(WriterContext *w, AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, int stream_idx, InputStream *ist, int in_program)
{
  AVStream *stream = ist->st;
...
  auto tcr = av_dict_get(stream->metadata, "timecode", NULL, 0);
  std::cerr << "Timecode: " << tcr->value << ", Total Frames: << stream->nb_frames << "\n";
```

The time code is the correct one that was embedded into the video.  The `nb_frames` is correctly the total number of video frames that I have.  What I can't get is the per-frame timecode.  I don't want to compute it if I don't have to, I want to know exactly what was stamped on each frame.  Is this possible?

```cpp
// Pseudocode for what I want
for(const auto& f : allOfMyFrames)
{
  std::cerr << "Frame number " << f.number << ", Timecode: " << f.timecode << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timecode, such as that in a MOV/MP4, is just a single packet with the starting timecode expressed as a rate-adjusted frame count. There is no per-frame timecode.